# Called C static library with everything wrapped in extern "C" and it's still not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm calling a C static-link library in VS2010 by wrapping the header file with extern "C", but I'm still getting a LNK2001: unresolved external symbol. I'm calling the same .lib file somewhere else with no problems and I'm reusing old code from somewhere else that definitely works. The code I'm using can be found at github.com/toots/microsoft-audio-watermarking. I'm trying to use the "thrabs" function found in hthres.h. I can't think of any obvious reasons it's not working. Here's the example code. `thrabs` is the c external. Is it possible my variable `_fm_lookup` which is normally defined in C++ is the problem?

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < NFREQ; i++) 
    _fm_lookup[i] = thrabs((0.5 + i) * (float) fs * 0.5 / (float) NFREQ);
```

the C static lib is being included by using

`extern "C"
{
    #include "htres.h"
}`

the error is

```
Error   37  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fm_lookup    C:\Users\David\Documents\Projects\watermarking\Builds\VisualStudio2010\internal2003.lib(hthres.obj)
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please! (This includes to post verbatim error messages in your question)

Comment: Do NOT start user-defined identifiers with an underscore ! (if your lib has a function named fm_lookup inside it ,it might not get linked in)

Comment: I removed the underscore, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Too bad, but it's illegal anyway,

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind going forward.

Comment: So you use it during compilation ,but do you actually link the library ?

Comment: I've included the internal2003.lib file as an additional dependency into the project, yes. It also shows up under the command line

Comment: what is the extension of the sourcefile with the function thrabs( ... ) ? if it's .cpp than your function is probably not a c-function but a c++-function.

Comment: I'm calling thrabs from a .cpp file, but thrabs is declared in a .h file. I've surrounded all the declarations with extern "c" since the static-library being used was created in c. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Did you try it without extern C around the include directive ? In regard to the c or c++ issue : many compilers determine how to compile (c or c++) from the extension used by source files ( .c == c and .cpp == c++)

Comment: I did ya, no dice :-(.

Comment: after reading your description of the problem again : In hthres.c you must have a reference to an externally defined symbol _fm_lookup ! If this symbol is to be defined by the user(s) of the library then this IMHO a design-flaw better to be corrected or documented better.

Comment: try extern C around the definition of _fm_lookup ( NOTE with the _ )

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure if I follow. I need to define somewhere _fm_lookup? Where would I define this and how would the .lib file know it's there.

Comment: you removed the undersore from _fm_lookup ,not ? put the underscore back (for now) and put extern C in front of the definition. If it builds well then that was a/the problem..

Comment: The compiler doesn't like that. Thanks for your help. This is painful.

Comment: sorry ,got sloppy ,meant of course extern "C"

Comment: I knew what you meant. It didn't like it because I was declaring inside a class, so I moved it outside and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder is it because the name of my .h and .cpp file is different.

Comment: Difference in filenames doesn't have influence. Has the source-file of hthres.obj a .cpp or a .c extension ?

Comment: I have no idea how to find that out since hthres is part of a .lib that I have no access to the internals of. It's 3rd party.

Comment: Almost out of ideas. Last idea : place your algorithm in a function in a .c file and call this new c-function instead.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and report back. Thanks for your time.

Comment: good luck, and sometimes painfull is educational

Comment: It worked. Couldn't go to bed without one last try!!! I've learned a lot today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Needed to move the offending code into its own c file and call it from there while using extern "C". Painful lesson learned.

Comment: Congrats ! Glad to see that my last suggestion worked.

Comment: how exactly was it done? how did you call it from C++? is it possible at all?